# Node js url.parse—href not returning the full url

Tags: node.js

I have the following very simple code snippet in node.js (running under **Windows 7**)

```
var path = url.parse(req.url, true).pathname;
var href = url.parse(req.url, true).href;

console.log("path " + path + "\r\n");
console.log("href " + href + "\r\n");
```

I invoke the listener with localhost:8080/test

I would expect to see:

```
path /test
href /localhost:8080/test
```

Instead I get

```
path /test
href /test
```

Why is href not the the full url?

Comment: `req.url` only contains the path, that's why routes are matched as `app.get('/test')`

Answer (score 2):

As @adeneo said in the comment, `req.url` only contains the path. There are two solutions, depending on whether you are using express or not.

**If using express:** You need to do the following:

```
var href = req.protocol + "://"+ req.get('Host') + req.url;
console.log("href " + href + "\r\n");
```

This wil output:

```
http://localhost:8080/test
```

Reference: http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.get

**If using node's http server**: Use the request's headers:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var href = "http://"+ req.headers.host + req.url;
  console.log("href " + href + "\r\n");
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

Reference: http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_headers

Comment: @ChrisG. That is a great point, and I certainly did not pay attention. Edit solves for both cases. Thanks!